# Safari cannot connect to localhost but can connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: mac, localhost, safari

For some reason, all of a sudden my Safari cannot connect to localhost because it cannot establish a secure connection. However, it is able to connect 127.0.0.1. Oddly enough Firefox is able to connect to localhost and 127.0.0.1. I believe it's some sort of certificate issue, but that's just a guess. What can I do so I can connect to localhost on Safari again?

Thanks

Comment: I feel like you're leaving out a lot of key details. What kind of webserver (or other software package with its own integrated web service) have you been running on your machine? Have you perhaps been experimenting with HSTS or HPKP security on a website you're developing on localhost?

Comment: I'm running MAMP. I recently upgraded from MAMP 3.5.x to the latest version. I did uninstall MAMP Pro which did some edits to the host file. I haven't been experimenting with either of those things. I did install a Docker image of cozy.io last night and removed it promptly. That was the first time I had some secure connection issues though it was able to be bypassed by adding an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably installed something on your machine that acts as a web server and uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to make sure your browser knows it should always use TLS (HTTPS) when connecting. Then you connected to it by pointing your browser at localhost, and now your browser believes it should only use HTTPS when connecting to localhost.

Apparently Safari stores its list of HSTS websites in `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`, so you should be able to fix it by editing that plist file to remove the entry for localhost, or by deleting that plist altogether if you don't mind resetting the whole list of sites Safari has learned to strictly require TLS for.

Comment: I think this is the solution, but the only problem is that it keeps adding the localhost entry after I start Safari. Even if I delete the plist.

Comment: Deleted this plist and restarted and this worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Note: This might not solve everyone's problem.

I am a MAMP user and noticed in my hosts settings that `127.0.0.1 localhost` was removed somehow. Type `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, type in your password, and then add these default lines back:

`127.0.0.1       localhost
::1              localhost`

This worked for me. I hope others find it helpful.